# How to search across more than one attribute in Jquery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an array of objects with structure similar to this:

```
$scope.usersList = [{
  "name": "John",
  "email": "john@xyz.com",
  "id": "abcd"
},{
  "name": "Jane",
  "email": "jane@xyz.com",
  "id": "efgh"
}];
```

I get the array after making an ajax call to the server. I am currently using jQuery UI Autocomplete in an angular app like this

```
$(input).autocomplete({
  source: $scope.usersList,
  appendTo: container,
  position: { 
    at: 'left bottom', 
    of: container 
  },
  select: function(e, v) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do something
  }
});
```

If the array simply consists of names, the above code works, but I want to search across "email" and "id" fields as well. e.g. if I type "abcd" in the search box I want to see John's name in the result list. I am unable to figure out how to proceed with this.

Comment: Implement `source` as a function that uses whatever filter logic you need. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try modifying your source as below:

```
$("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        minLength:2,
        **source: function (request, response) {
            var temp = [];
                   usersList.filter(buildResponse);

                   function buildResponse(p){
                      for (var key in p) {
                      if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                       if(p[key].indexOf(request.term) > -1){
                        temp.push({
                        "label" : p[key],
                        "value" : p                     
                        });                      
                       }
                        }
                      }
                   }
                   console.log(temp);
                  response(temp); 
            }**,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        // Prevent value from being put in the input:
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        // Set the next input's value to the "value" of the item.
        console.log(ui.item);
        event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
```

//usersList = $scope.usersList (as mentioned in your question)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/501/

Comment: This matches only the id.

Comment: Can you please check the fiddle?

Comment: Ah, just noticed it's case sensitive.

Comment: Fix the casing, after that it's a nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of stumbling, I managed to get the search term to be any property. This should work in your case (just substitute `var usersList` with your collection):

```
<input id="in" type="input" class="ui-autocomplete-input" />

var usersList = [{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@xyz.com",
    "id": "abcd"
  }, {
    "name": "Jane",
    "email": "jane@xyz.com",
    "id": "efgh"
}];

$("#in").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        function hasMatch(s) {
            return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
        var i, l, obj, matches = [];

        if (request.term === "") {
            response([]);
            return;
        }

        for (i = 0, l = usersList.length; i < l; i++) {
            obj = usersList[i];
            if (hasMatch(obj.name) || hasMatch(obj.email) || hasMatch(obj.id)) {
                if ($.inArray(obj, matches) < 1) { // remove duplicates
                    matches.push({
                        "label": obj.name
                        //add here other properties you might need
                    })
                }
            }
            response(matches);
        }
    }
});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qg50zwv3/